Reset or change monitor numbering in Windows monitor settings
I know that you normally can't change the numbers 1, 2, 3 etc. that Windows assigns to the connected monitors. At least I'm not aware of any way to do so after much research.
"Normally" referring to the case where internal processor iGPUs or discrete dGPUs and "normal" monitor connections like DisplayPort or HDMI are involved.
However I believe it should be possible to change or at least reset the numbering when connecting (several) monitors via Thunderbolt or USB-C because in that case the numbering probably is based on which monitor was connected first, second and so on.
Is anyone aware of the registry key that has to be deleted to start over with that numbering?

Why don’t you just rearrange the displays and set the display you want as primary?

I'm commuting weekly with the laptop between office and home office.
I have three monitors at both locations. The monitors are connected via different eGPUs and/or Thunderbolt adapters at the two locations, and so Windows does not assign the same numbers to the monitors at the two locations.
At home, the numbering/monitor arrangement is 3-2-1 from left to right, and at the office, the numbering is 2-1-3. However, I need the numbering to be the same at both locations for certain reasons.

Can you explain any further those "certain reasons"?

Sure. I'm using a software called Actual Window Manager that does countless things to program windows relative to certain monitors, using the Windows-assigned monitor IDs.

@David.P, please edit the question to provide more details.
